# Workflow Error on Workflow Moved from other Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I just wrote a long Pnp-based Powershell script that creates a templated site. It works great except for my most important workflow, which does not. My other workflow which runs first on the same list works fine, but the one that creates a subsite does not. It completes, but throws an InternalServerError:

> Completed call to Add Site with response code: InternalServerError

**UPDATE**
The error I'm getting is in the final web service call. When I go to the URL I get this:

> The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'Add'. The
>   operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use
>   correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.

I'm not sure where I can find out more info. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the GET method to POST method in the final web service call in the problematic workflow.

Comment: It's a POST in the workflow. The Get is from the browser.

Comment: Delete, re-add and re-configure the final web service in the problematic workflow. Then publish the workflow and check the result.